# Find patterns in list of sets with fast performance

Tags: python

**The setup**

Given a list of sets:

```
mylist = [{'a','the'}, {'red', 'brown', 'white'}, {'dog', 'cat'}]
```

I need to verify if any given list is contained element-wise in mylist

```
pattern_match(['a', 'red', 'dog'], mylist) # True

pattern_match(['a', 'grey', 'cat'], mylist) # False, because of 'grey'
```

**The original solution**

I expressed `pattern_match` as

```
def pattern_match(sequence, patterns):
    if len(sequence) == len(patterns):
        return all([sequence[i] in patterns[i] for i in range(len(patterns))])
    else:
        return False
```

This works fairly well for checking one single sequence like `['a','brown','dog']`, and the code is clean and understandable

**The problem with checking many sequences**

I need to do this for a very high number of sequences like `['a','brown','dog']`, on fairly long lists-of-sets, in a timely fashion

Given

```
mylist = [{'a','the'}, {'red', 'brown', 'white'}, {'dog', 'cat'}]
mysequences = [['a','brown','dog'], ['the','yellow','horse'], ...] # len(mysequences) is very high
```

what is the best approach **with performance in mind** to achieve the same result as the code below:

```
[pattern_match(seq, mylist) for seq in mysequences] # yields [True, False, ...]
```

Comment: Currently you're searching through every set, even if one is set to `False`. One method could be to stop searching through the list of sets once a `False` value is found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can optimize the performance in your `pattern_match` function:

```
def pattern_match(sequence, patterns):
    if len(sequence) == len(patterns):
        return all(item in my_set for item, my_set in zip(sequence, patterns))
    else:
        return False
```

By getting rid of the list comprehension we can stop checking once the first such check fails.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

```
def pattern_match(sequence, patterns):
    seq = set(sequence)
    u = set()
    for pattern in patterns:
        u.update(pattern) #includes pattern members in u
    return seq.issubset(u) # checks if sequence is subset of u
```

`issubset()` and `update()` are documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). But depending on the use case, you might need to construct u outside the function and pass the final value to `pattern_match` if `my_list` is fixed for many calls to avoid reconstruction of u in every call:

```
u = set()
for pattern in my_list:
    u.update(pattern)

results = [pattern_match(seq, u) for seq in mysequences]
```